# stop automatico en Progressbar en tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter, progressbar

Buen dia, Tengo un problema con este pequeño codigo. Busco lograr que la barra de progreso se pare al 100% luego de completar un ciclo de for.

hasta el momento solo he logrado que la barra se llene dependiendo de la rapidez que se ponga en `start(10)`. al llenarse la barra el vuelve a repetir una y otra vez. Se que puedo hacerle un `stop()` con otro boton pero yo busco que al llegar al 100% se pare y al volver a darle al boton vuelva a comenzar de 0 a 100.

por ejemplo:
me contara del 1 al 10, Entonces cada porcentaje seria un 10% y al 100% para hasta presionar de nuevo el boton y comenzar de 0 a 100% de nuevo.

```
x = 10
for i in range(1,x+1):
   print(i)
```

Esto es lo que he logrado hasta el momento

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


def clicked():
   pgbar.start(10)
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")


pgbar = Progressbar(
   root,
   length=200,
   orient=HORIZONTAL,
   maximum = 100,
   value = 0,
   mode = 'determinate'
   )
pgbar.pack()

btn = Button(
   root,
   text= 'Click Me',
   command = clicked,
   )
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: y si interrumpes la funcion al llegar a 100%?? tambien puedes usar Tkinter.END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizás esto te funcione:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


process = 0


def clicked():
    global process
    if process == pgbar['maximum']:
        #Reiniciar
        terminado['text'] = ""
        process = 0
        pgbar['value'] = 0
    process += 10
    pgbar['value'] = process
    terminado['text'] = str(process) + "%"
    if pgbar['value'] >= pgbar['maximum']:
        terminado['text'] = "100% completado"
        return
    root.after(100, clicked)


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

pgbar = Progressbar(root, length=200, orient=HORIZONTAL, maximum=100, value=0, mode='determinate')
pgbar.pack()

terminado = Label(root, text="")
terminado.pack()

btn = Button(
    root,
    text='Click Me',
    command=clicked,
)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```